# How to remove polyline from maps with Polyline Manager?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I have setup my code as such:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("encoded_polyline");

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       PolylineManager polylineManager = new PolylineManager(mGoogleMap);
       PolylineManager.Collection polylineCollection = polylineManager.newCollection();

       for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         encodedPolyline = ds.child("polyline").getValue().toString()
         decodedPolyline = PolyUtil.decode(encodedPolyline);
         polylineCollection.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(decodedPolyline));
       }
   }
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                
   }
}
```

I tried polylineCollection.clear() and it does not do anything at all. Polyline still remain

Comment: When exactly would you like to remove the polyline?

Comment: @AlexMamo I would like to remove the polyline everytime the function this database is called. I put the polylineCollection.clear() under PolylineManager.Collection polylineCollection initialization but it does not erase the polyline

Comment: Step 1 is to stop ignoring potential errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. --- After that, I recommend debugging the app locally. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.